# Select only up to 2 lines for orders which have products with more than 1 item ordered

Tags: mysql, sql, database

[image]

I would like to display all orders which have more than 1 item but to display only 2 rows if they have more than 2 items

[image]

If you have any ideas i will appreciate it, thank you.

Comment: Does it matter which 2 rows? (If there are more than 2 rows for an id.)

Comment: @jarlh It looks like he wants the first two row numbers, telling by the expected output.

Comment: Yes, thank you i need the first two rows. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have a row number column for each `id`, which greatly simplifies the query.  In this case, we can arrive at your expected output by just joining the `ORDERS` table to a subquery which identifies `id` having 2 or more records associated with them.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM ORDERS t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id
    FROM ORDERS
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
) t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.rown_num <= 2
```

Comment: May i ask what HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2 suppose to do?

Comment: Sure, `HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2` restricts to order `id` groups which have two or more items.  This is your requirement.

Comment: Thank you, what if i have the row_num in a separate table after your code i JOIN two more table and just change WHERE t3.row_num<=2. I believe this suppose to work however when i have  HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2 it gives me no result when i change it to  HAVING COUNT(*) <= i have output however not the desired one. Again thank you, and if you have any recommendation i will appreciate it. :)

Comment: I would recommend that you ask a new question if your schema has changed.  This isn't a good way to get help.

Answer (score 1):

try this simple solution

```
SELECT * FROM orders od WHERE od.id IN( SELECT id FROM orders o GROUP BY o.id HAVING o.id HAVING COUNT(o.id)>1)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:
the first join will give you the rows you want and the second join will add the rown_num field

```
  select a.id,
           a.item_num,
           b.rown_num
    from
    (select id,
           item_num
    from orders 
    where rown_num in (1,2)
    group by id,item_num
    having count(id)>=2)a
    inner join (select *
                 from orders )b on a.id=b.id
                               and a.item_num=b.item_num
```